# Form Post from another site (cross domain and cross web servers)

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, forms, form-post, http-post

I want to enable form Post from another sites.suppose i have one Form in my site and i want to enable that form post for another sites.

i have asp.net web page www.xyx.com\formpost.aspx
with field EMail.and i want to enable my page form post.for all any one who post data into my site.
like

1)www.test.com\emailpost.php Form Post from this site.

```
var str = JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeObject());
 $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-16',             
              dataType: 'json',
              url: "www.xyx.com/formpost.aspx/SaveCustomerEmail",
              success: function (msg) {
                  alert('done');
              },
              error: function (msg) { 
                alert(JSON.stringify(msg)) }
          });
```

2)www.test2.com\emailpost.jsp Form Post from this site.

```
var str = JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeObject());
 $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-16',             
              dataType: 'json',
              url: "www.xyx.com/formpost.aspx/SaveCustomerEmail",
              success: function (msg) {
                  alert('done');
              },
              error: function (msg) { 
                alert(JSON.stringify(msg)) }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a CORS policy on the receiving domain (`www.xyx.com`)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

To allow requests from *any domain*.

For a more involved look at CORS see: http://fritsvancampen.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/cross-site-origin-requests-aka-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to use a complete url, such as `'http://www.xyx.com/formpost.aspx/SaveCustomerEmail'`, otherwise the browser will be looking for a resource called `www.xyz.com` on your server.
2. You're going to run into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  [jQyery's `.ajax()` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) includes a `JSONP` data type to get around this.  The server needs to allow cross-domain requests, of course.